# Primefaces 5.1 calendar popup doesn't execute the valueChange event

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm try to use the primefaces calendar with popup in this way:

```
<p:calendar pattern="yyyy-MMM-dd" value="#{controller.beginDate}" mask="true" navigator="true">
    <f:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{controller.onChange}" />
</p:calendar>
```

And here is the relative controller:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Controller {
    private Date beginDate;

    public Date getBeginDate() {
        return beginDate;
    }

    public void setBeginDate(Date beginDate) {
        this.beginDate = beginDate;
    }

    public void onChange() {
        // do somethings
    }
}
```

The problem: if I change the value from the input field, the event will be execute, but if I change it from the popup, the event will NOT execute.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `valueChange` event is only triggered by HTML DOM `change` event. This is indeed not triggered when the input value is manipulated by JavaScript means.

You need the `dateSelect` event instead. And, in PrimeFaces components, you'd better use `<p:ajax>` instead of `<f:ajax>`.

```
<p:calendar ...>
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{controller.onChange()}" />
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{controller.onChange()}" />
</p:calendar>
```

#### See also:

- [PrimeFaces Users Guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html)

Comment: The downside to this is that **both** events will be send in PrimeFaces if you use the calendar component with the option to both use the 'calendar' part and the input field. Will investigate this and maybe file a patch to PF if I can 'fix' this

Comment: This solution only works as long as I don't use <f:converter converterId="myConverter" />

With a converter, the new date is not properly set in the backing bean for "valueChange" events. It only works for "dateSelect" events.

I'll post this as a separate Question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150568/primefaces-calendar-with-converter-doesnt-update-correctly-upon-ajax-change-e

Answer (score 1):

Try using the PrimeFaces dateSelect event.

From PrimeFaces documentation:

Calendar provides a dateSelect ajax behavior event to execute an instant ajax selection whenever a date is selected. If you define a method as a listener, it will be invoked by passing an org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent instance.

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date}">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{bean.handleDateSelect}" />
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: The dateSelect will not be fired of you use the input box. But if you add both, they are both send, so you get two events on the server. Should be optimized in PF in if possible